# Why do web podcast players never have a volume control?

Tags: audio

I've noticed this trend with all web podcast players like overcast etc. It's annoying because I don't always want to load up itunes, or spotify etc just to listen and I often listen while I'm doing other things.

​

So I find I have to lower the system volume and then raise the volume in other applications up to max if I want to be able to hear the podcast but also hear something else over the top.

Comment: I haven't noticed this problem.  What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Firefox on windows

Comment: It just depends on the implementation of the particular video/audio player. I did a search for some podcasts and the web players for some some do have audio control, while others don't. As for Why, you'll have to ask the developers.

Answer (score 2):

No volume control on the player is an Apple thing. It's in Apple's iOS guidelines that iOS apps shouldn't have their own volume controls. Apple wants their device to control the volume.

Here's some general referencing in [Apple's iOS Human Interface Guidelines on Audio](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/audio/)